# How to run a script automatically when CPU usage is high

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Apache/MySQL/Ubuntu stack on AWS EC2 here.

For some reason, my web server spikes to 99% and my server becomes completely unusable. It is insanely frustrating. I don't have to the ability to troubleshoot the issue, because the server is completely unresponsive, and I can't login. I know it's something to do with MYSQL, and that is it. It will slowly increase CPU usage until it gets to 100% and I can't do anything but forcefully Stop and Start the instance via the AWS UI.

My work around thought is to automatically restart MySQL/Apache if the CPU usage reaches a certain point. I was messing with `cpu-limit`, but I can't figure out how to get this to attach to PIDs already running.

I just want to be able to limit the CPU until it gets to that point, then I can try to read the logs or see what is going on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Under /proc/PID, you find the `stat` file, which includes CPU usage figures. A version of that data is in /proc/PID/status (human-readable). See `man proc` for details. I would run my script based on the `utime` and `stime` values. To limit the CPU, try `renice` or put suspicious processes in a Cgroup (I don't remember, off the cuff, how you can limit CPU this way, but it's not too hard. Tutorials and kernel information are not hard to find).

Comment: You could also sort the output of `ps -el` according to the C column to find high CPU users, or try `top`'s batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, turn on the slowlog and have `long_query_time=1` (or less).  After the next spike in CPU, use `pt-query-digest` to analyze the slowlog.  (We can help if needed.)

That will discover which queries are taking the longest time (hence probably using the most CPU).  Often the "cure" is to make a better, composite, index for some table.

More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 0):

Running an extra thing at high load requires there to be some capacity remaining. On a systemd system, make it share its slice with [resource control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

```
systemctl edit mysql.service
```

Add to the unit CPU and IO weights lower than the default of 100. CPU quota is % of one CPU, and you didn't mention the number of CPUs, so this an absolute limit may need adjusting. Also enable CPU, IO, and memory accounting.

```
[Service]
CPUAccounting=yes
CPUWeight=50
#CPUQuota=90%
IOAccounting=yes
IOWeight=50
MemoryAccounting=yes
TasksAccounting=yes
```

After editing the drop in configs, `systemctl daemon-reload`.  Use `systemd-cgtop` to see resource consumption by service. In particular, confirm the resource really is used by the database and not httpd.

See also: [How to limit a systemd service to “play nice” with the CPU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494843/how-to-limit-a-systemd-service-to-play-nice-with-the-cpu)

This doesn't explain the performance issue, only lowers the priority of mysql enough to hopefully let other things run. Use Linux performance tools to assess the workload. A starting tool set is [Linux Performance Analysis in 60,000 Milliseconds](https://netflixtechblog.com/linux-performance-analysis-in-60-000-milliseconds-accc10403c55) from when Brendan Gregg was at Netflix. These essentials need repeating:

```
uptime
dmesg | tail
vmstat 1
mpstat -P ALL 1
pidstat 1
iostat -xz 1
free -m
sar -n DEV 1
sar -n TCP,ETCP 1
top
```

I suspect the box is starved for storage I/O or memory, but I have no evidence of that. Examine the system in detail from a web server and database perspective.